# Being redirected to the wrong place - sometimes

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have a javascript setInterval that checks an external page every 5 seconds for mail, I am finding sometimes that if I login or click a form submit at the same time as the request goes out, I sometimes find myself looking at a Y or a N (what my JS was to intercept) instead of the real link I wanted to go to.

How does one debug this?  I am using firefox with firebug, my app is using PHP with javascript.

EDIT: it's almost as if the onComplete is being missed by java, and it just dumps it as the user is signing in.... it only happens when someone is changing pages and the java is running at the same time.

**EDIT 2:** If you want to see this for yourself,  you'll need visit my site and create an account and go through the signup process (2-3 mins to do tops), the website is http://mikesandmegs.com and the beta password is **goldfish**. What you want to do is login just as the check mail sends its request off. Its like I need to cancel something or tell java to throw the callback out or something. You should see the requests every 5 seconds, (well it adds 5 seconds each request) but you'll see.  **It may take a couple try's or some luck, but it is reproducible.**

This is the javascript that is running (i think I have it all posted) If I seem to be missing anything, let me know.  I also posted an htnl input html that the javascript checks...

```
<input id="hasMail" type="hidden" value="y">

<script type='text/javascript'>
    mailTimer = setInterval("checkMail();", 10000);

function checkMail()
{
    // should we check the mail now?
    if ($('hasMail').value == "y")
    {
        // remove mail new mail alert (mail-check.php returns y or n
        new Ajax.Request('mail-check.php', 
        { 
            method: 'post', 
            postBody: '',
            onComplete: checkMailNotify 
        });
    }
}

    function checkMailNotify(req)
    {
        if (req.responseText.length > 5)
        {
            $('hasMail').value = "n";
            clearInterval (mailTimer);
            return;
        }

        if (req.responseText == "y")
        {
            $('hasMail').value = "n";
            $('topMessage').update('<a href="/mail-inbox.php">You have new mail...</a>');
            $('alertBox').appear();
            clearInterval (mailTimer);
        }
        else
        {
            clearInterval (mailTimer);
            mailInterval = mailInterval + 5000;
            mailTimer = setInterval("checkMail();", mailInterval);
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: you could start by posting the code that's causing this

Comment: Hrm, looks like nothing is amiss to me. 

Is your test site public? Can we get a link to it, if it is? 

If I were debugging this, I'd ... Wait, I just noticed you said you were looking at XML. It looks like you're script is expecting to return just a few characters... Is your script emitting the XML or is that magically appearing?

Comment: sorry, i said I was looking at xml, I made a mistake just a plain screen with a Y or a N that my javascript was supposed to intercept

Comment: let me get it up on a public site...

Comment: Does it also happen in other browsers? Maybe you can rule out it being a Firefox bug?

Comment: Ok, you'll need to create an account and go theough the signup process, the website is http://mikesandmegs.com and the beta password is goldfish.  What you want to do is login just as the check mail sends its request off.  Its like I need to cancel something or tell java to throw the callback out or something.  You should see the requests every 5 seconds, (well it adds 5 seconds each request) but you'll see.

Comment: I have to ask -- Why are you using `setInterval` when you clear it every time? I would think `setTimeout` would be a better fit.

Comment: @Jonathan good call, I will do that.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is nowhere near a solution, but it WILL help to increase the 5 second interval, even to something like 30 seconds.  I've done work with mailservers before, and we often came across problems where people would have e.g their iphone as well as their desktop mail client ping the server at very short intervals.  This would result in confusing (to them) failures because of locks.

So yeah, 5 seconds for messages is very quick (it doesn't look like chat but rather just messages, is that right?).  At best if you do that then the problem will happen a lot less if it all.  You will however have the horrible knowledge that it can happen.

Please don't take this as an attempt at a solution to your problem.  just a suggestion.

Comment: I appreciate the feed back, thanks.  I was unsure how often I should check it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is that while changing pages, the data from the mail-check.php is clashing with the new request that is coming back from the network at the same time. I think a possible solution is to disable the setInterval whenever you change a page or submit a form, then re-enable it after loading the new data.

Something like:

```
<input type="button" onClick="clearInterval('mailTimer'); this.submit()" />
...
```

Comment: What if the mail-check.php request was just sent out just a millisecond before they hit that?  It's a race condition either way isn't it?